# Can we replace the default document uri to a value from the document itself during mlcp ingestion in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I want to replace the default document uri of the file to a value from the file's content.

For example - the default uri is /test/Invoice.xml

I want to replace the doc uri to

```
/Invoice_{current date time from file from field DateCreated}.xml
```

The file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///D:/Mapforce/Projects/schema/Test.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ID>f1258d4ae0df43d5a1e05ce9139f0ed2</ID>
    <SystemRef>22000041</SystemRef>
    <DateCreated>2022-09-06T19:07:46.3492849+01:00</DateCreated>
    <TimeSaved>240</TimeSaved>
    <ManyReasons/>
    <SubmissionUser>System</SubmissionUser>
    <InternalBusinessUnit>Finance</InternalBusinessUnit>
    <Direction>Inbound</Direction>
</Test>
```

How can I do it using mlcp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Controlling Database URIs During Ingestion](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_14982)

> By default, the document URIs created by mlcp during ingestion are determined by the input source. The tool supports several command line options for modifying this default behavior.

- [Transforming the Default URI](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_42798)

  > Use the following options to tailor the database URI of inserted documents:
  >
  > - **-output_uri_replace** performs one or more string substitutions on the default URI.
  > - **-output_uri_prefix** prepends a string to the URI after substitution.
  > - **-output_uri_suffix** appends a string to the URI after substitution.
  >
  > The -output_uri_replace option accepts a comma delimited list of regular expression and replacement string pairs.

If you are [applying a custom transformation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_82518), then you can also control the URI of the document. Inside of the transform method, set the `uri` property of the `$content` map with whatever value you want. i.e. `map:put($content, "uri", "myCustomURI.xml")`. See: [Example: Changing the URI and Document Type](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_17589)

So, in your custom transform you could XPath to the DateCreated element and let a variable:

```
let $created := map:get($content, "value")/Test/DateCreated
```

and then use it to construct the desired URI (may want to normalize/format the DateCreated value for a clean URI)

```
map:put($content, "/Invoice_"||$created||".xml")
```

Comment: Thanks Mads, but while I am using mlcp to ingest file -can I call this custom xquery to trasform the uri in runtime ?  How to exactly use this while using mlcp.

Comment: Yes, you can. That is exactly what the Example: Changing the URI and Document Type that I linked to are doing.

Comment: Thanks Mad, but I am getting a namespace issue after implementing this. And not able to figure out the bug. I will open another question for that.